# For each column, rowname of top n values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

as the title says, what I'd like to have is the rownames of the top N values of each column. I have a dataframe containing TV series characters on the rows and each column is one episode. In order to get a list of most relevant characters, I think taking maybe the three most speaking characters in each episode might be a nice way. I have thought about just looping through each column, ordering it, taking the name and adding it to an array, but there must be a more efficient way to do this.
Thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: Can you post sample data using dput()?

Comment: @BillO'Brien Sure, i'll update in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using the `mtcars` dataset. It uses `order()`
to sort the row names based on the values of each column, using
`tail()`. `sapply()` is used to apply to all columns and return a
data.frame:

```r
rn <- row.names(mtcars)
f <- function(x) tail(rn[order(x)], n = 3)
sapply(mtcars, f)
```

```
##      mpg              cyl                disp                  hp              
## [1,] "Lotus Europa"   "Pontiac Firebird" "Chrysler Imperial"   "Camaro Z28"    
## [2,] "Fiat 128"       "Ford Pantera L"   "Lincoln Continental" "Ford Pantera L"
## [3,] "Toyota Corolla" "Maserati Bora"    "Cadillac Fleetwood"  "Maserati Bora" 
##      drat             wt                    qsec            vs            
## [1,] "Ford Pantera L" "Cadillac Fleetwood"  "Toyota Corona" "Fiat X1-9"   
## [2,] "Porsche 914-2"  "Chrysler Imperial"   "Valiant"       "Lotus Europa"
## [3,] "Honda Civic"    "Lincoln Continental" "Merc 230"      "Volvo 142E"  
##      am              gear             carb            
## [1,] "Ferrari Dino"  "Ford Pantera L" "Ford Pantera L"
## [2,] "Maserati Bora" "Ferrari Dino"   "Ferrari Dino"  
## [3,] "Volvo 142E"    "Maserati Bora"  "Maserati Bora"
```